# Converting JavaScript generated documents/pages to PDF

Tags: java, javascript, pdf-generation, itext, xhtmlrenderer

I'm using xhtmlrenderer + iText in Java to generate PDFs for some pages in my application. I've managed to convert some pages already. However, I came across a limitation to this approach where it can't convert pages dynamically created using JavaScript scripts (some by JQuery). Are there other available tools for this?

Thanks.

Comment: i've also looked, though i was looking for a python solution.  i couldn't find one that supported javascript as far as i remember.

Comment: If this is something that only needs to be done once, and not dynamically, you might see if your Print dialog has an option for PDF output.

Comment: One approach might be to use JavaScript to grab the entire DOM after a page is stable, serialize the DOM, and then send it to the server for PDF processing.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).  It's a PDF converter sitting on top of web kit, complete with its JS environment.  I haven't tried it myself (yet).

Comment: I'm not really sure if that's what I need. I'm actually doing some sort of a reporting tool for a Web application that can generate PDF versions of the pages.

Comment: I'm a committer on iText.  I know what it can do, and I know its HTML converter isn't its strong suit.  Call wkhtmltopdf via the command line in java.   HTML in, PDF out, and it'll handle any and all DOM script you throw its way.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can I do this over Java? As in via a method call?

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);  Or perhaps some JNI calls.